# Magento 2 categories import

Tags: magento2, import

May I know how to do categories import in Magento 2?
I did not see the option in "System>Import" or in the "Products>Categories" section of the backend.

It is really puzzling the best Ecommerce CMS in the world such as magento does not even permit user to import categories.

I have 500+ categories but I don't want to type them one by one.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 does not have a separate categories import, but you can have categories created when importing products. You need to add a "categories" column to your products csv file that lists the categories the product should be placed in. By default, multiple categories are separated by a comma.  Sub-categories are indicated by a slash.

So a categories entry like:
"Mens/Pants/Jeans, Mens/Pants/Casual"

would create these categories when the products where imported.

- Mens

  - Pants

    - Jeans
    - Casual

If you aren't sure how to format the Products CSV file, create a few entries in the admin interface and then export the products to get a sample file.

Comment: Beth , thank you so much for your response :) Does this mean there will be no way for me to import category description, category meta , and category URL ? Prestashop has a complete category import fields in a separate import process than magento. It's just their SEO perform so poorly.

Comment: I've never tried importing those fields and I don't know of a way to do it.  You might want to check on https://marketplace.magento.com to see if someone has created a module to do that import.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following script to bulk import categories magento 2.

```
 foreach ( $arrResult as $import_category ) {

    try {

        $enabled = ( strtolower( $import_category[16] ) == 'true' ) ? 1 : 0;
        $parentId = ( $import_category[1] == 0 )? '2' : $list[$import_category[1]];            

        $url = strtolower($import_category[2]);
        $cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        /// Add a new sub category under root category
        $category = $categoryFactory->create();
        $category->setName(ucfirst($import_category[2]));
        $category->setIsActive( $enabled );
        $category->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
        $category->setData('description', strip_tags($import_category[11]));
        $category->setParentId($parentId);
        $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
        $category->setImage( $import_category[6], $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/
        $category->setStoreId($storeId);
        $rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
        $category->save();
        $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
        echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
        print_r($e);
    }
```

Click here for detailed explanation . http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-magento-2-categories-programmatically/

Comment: I have try this code but not working for me.